# How to get an array of images from internal storage in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, bitmap, storage

i'm using Android Studio and I need to create simple slider. What is the easiest way to get an array of all images from internal device storage? I need a bitmap array or an array of a pathes to those images.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I'm trying to understand MediaStore.Images , but still no result.

Comment: @Alejandro did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CursorLoader for this. Have a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.html to understand what fields you need to request while creating the loader.